# Single massive array cell dynamically allocated behaving as an array with multiple smaller cells

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am having some strange behavior that when i wrote the code thought was normal behavior.

In my code i allocate memory for a one cell array of the same size as the file. I then try to access this array using `image[i]` as if it were an array with multiple cells.

What i don't understand is why does this work? If i used `int` instead of `char`, would it behave similarly but with half or less of the "cells"?

```
char *testImage = "testdata/TestPng.png";
char *image;
int c;
long fSize = 0;
long i = 0;
FILE *fp;

// open image
fp = fopen(testImage, "rb");

// find file size
fseek(fp, 0l, SEEK_END);
fSize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

// allocate memory
image = calloc(1, fSize*sizeof(char))

// read from file and store in image buffer
while( ( c = fget(fp) ) != EOF ) {
    image[i] = (char) c;
    i++;
}

/*
Usage of the image buffer and later clean up
.
.
.
*/
```

Comment: There's nothing to be surprised by. Arrays and pointers to valid memory are mostly the same thing, so there's no reason you can't access them both either with pointer arithmetic or indexing.

Comment: `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`. So it also works for pointers.

Comment: I encourage you to not read your file character by character (by _fgetc_ rather than _fget_) but to use _fread_. By definition `sizeof(char)` is 1

Comment: Anon9128309182309812, With `char *image;` --> `int *image;` (and `calloc(1, fSize * sizeof(char))` --> `calloc(1, fSize*sizeof(int))`, yes things would work the alike yet with more memory.  Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: chux, I was thinking more of not casting the `fgtc` result to `char`. If I remember correctly, it gives type conversion error if i don't.